# How to make good market/shopping/grocery list in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, lists

I want to make a [market list](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=ZxF&channel=fs&tbm=isch&q=market+list&chips=q:market+list,online_chips:shopping&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwiomGhujZAhWIKo8KHRKCBiMQ4lYIKSgD&biw=1252&bih=614&dpr=1.09) where the column quantity is blank. The hard copy of the list will be used as a template for market list. Housewife/House keeper will fill the quantity in the hard copy she will need corresponding to the item.

Now, my question is that is there any good package that makes the market list good one?

MWE(compile using `xelatex`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
%\setmainlanguage{bengali}
%\setotherlanguage{english}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}
%\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{1.5cm}}}
  Name\\
  \toprule
Rice\\
\midrule
pulse\\
\midrule
Salt\\
\midrule
Oil\\
\midrule
Pepper\\
\midrule
Onion\\
\midrule
Garlic\\
\midrule
Ginger\\
\midrule
Salad\\
\midrule
Chicken\\
\midrule
Spice\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AlanMunn I changed the Bangla text to English.

Comment: It's still not clear what your question is, though.

Comment: @AlanMunn I try to edit again.

Comment: @AlanMunn I edited again. If further editing needed tell me.

Comment: @AlanMunn As I change the bangla text we can remove our comment  otherwise people can confused seeing the comment.

Comment: Your example will still give an error if I try to compile without having the font Akaash installed. Like Alan Munn, I don't understand the question anyway. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @cfr You can use any font/language I have no problem. But, keep in mind that your solution should work in Bengali also since ultimately I have to implement the solution in Bengali.

Comment: My point was that your example code still has the problem @AlanMunn pointed out, since most people will still be unable to compile it. I am extremely unlikely to offer a solution given that I have no idea what the problem is. However, I'll bear that criterion in mind should my crystal ball come up with anything plausible. Right now, it's just displaying an error and asking to be rebooted, but I tried that already and it didn't fix anythng.

Comment: @cfr I edited again. See now. if any query tell me.

Comment: @cfr I made the question very simpler now. Deleted `minipage`.

Comment: @AlanMunn see the edited question, now it is very simpler than previous.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\raggedcolumns
\newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[2cm][l]{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\foreach \x in {Rice,pulse,Salt,Oil,Pepper,Onion,Garlic,Ginger,Salad,Chicken,Spice}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Looks good, but I like one column.

Comment: So remove the `multicols` environment.