# How to give a header to the blank column?

Tags: tables, header-footer, columns

From this site I found a table code where a column is blank. And there he didn't use `&` for each rows, just put a `\hspace` to the header.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|@{\hspace{1em}}|}
  \hline
  A \\
  \hline
  B \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|l|@{\hspace{2em}}|}
  \hline
  A \\
  \hline
  B \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Source: [How to make enough space in empty column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224510/how-to-make-enough-space-in-empty-column)

My question is I want to make this type of table(no necessary the vertical line) where some columns are blanked, but have the header. And I don't want to put `&` for each rows. I want to do something like `\begin{tabular}{|l|@\header{Quantity{\hspace{1em}}}|}`
I need this for the question [How to make good market/shopping/grocery list in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419815/how-to-make-good-market-list-in-latex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's the last column that doesn't have any content, and if vertical rules are not required, you can just do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Name & Quantity \\
A \\
B \\
C
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

You can end a table row with `\\` before the last column, it's not required to add all the `&`.

[image: output of code]

Comment: I tried something similar of this, but error was occurred for something.

Answer (score 2):

A hacky way of doing it, but the following should work in most cases. `\myheader` takes:

- one optional argument specifying the alignment where `r` right-aligns, `c` centres, and everything else left-aligns.
- After that optional argument follows a mandatory argument containing the contents of the header of the first column.
- After that there is an optional argument that needs to be entered as `[<alignment>,<width>]`, where `<alignment>` again is `r` for right-alignment, `c` for centred or `j` for justified and everything else is left-aligned with fixed `<width>`. If the optional argument is not given, the content is left aligned, but without fixed width.
- And finally the contents of the second column header

Code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myStrCMP[2]
  {%
    \bgroup
      \def\tmpa{#1}%
      \def\tmpb{#2}%
      \ifx\tmpa\tmpb
        \egroup
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \else
        \egroup
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \fi
  }

\newcommand\myheader[2][l]
  {%
    \myStrCMP{#1}{c}{\hfill#2\hfill}
      {%
        \myStrCMP{#1}{r}{\hfill#2}{#2\hfill}%
      }
    \myheader@i
  }
\def\myheader@i%
  {%
    \@ifnextchar[
      {\myheader@ii}
      {\myheader@iii}%
  }
\long\def\myheader@ii[#1,#2]#3%
  {%
    \myStrCMP{#1}{r}
      {\myheader@iii{\parbox{\dimexpr#2-2\tabcolsep\relax}{\raggedleft#3}}}
      {%
        \myStrCMP{#1}{c}
          {%
            \myheader@iii
              {%
                \parbox
                  {\dimexpr#2-2\tabcolsep\relax}{\centering#3}%
              }%
          }
          {%
            \myStrCMP{#1}{j}
              {%
                \myheader@iii{\parbox{\dimexpr#2-2\tabcolsep\relax}{#3}}%
              }
              {%
                \myheader@iii
                  {\parbox{\dimexpr#2-2\tabcolsep\relax}{\raggedright#3}}%
              }
          }%
      }%
  }
\newcommand\myheader@iii[1]
  {%
    \rlap{\hskip2\tabcolsep#1}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{|l|@{\hspace{5em}}|}
  \hline
  \myheader{1col}{2col}\\
  \hline
  Abc is longer than header\\
  \hline
  B\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}[]{|l|@{\hspace{5em}}|}
  \hline
  \myheader[c]{1col}[c,5em]{2col}\\
  \hline
  Abc is longer than header\\
  \hline
  B\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}[]{|l|@{\hspace{5em}}|}
  \hline
  \myheader[r]{1col}[r,5em]{2col}\\
  \hline
  Abc is longer than header\\
  \hline
  B\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}[]{|l|@{\hspace{5em}}|}
  \hline
  \myheader[l]{1col}[l,5em]{2col with long header}\\
  \hline
  Abc is longer than header\\
  \hline
  B\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\multicolumn`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|@{\hspace{6em}}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{Quantity}\\
  \hline
  A \\
  \hline
  B \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see this https://pasteboard.co/HbDrymm.png

Comment: Or use no vertical line and put header for each column.